# MongoDb - Query for specific subdocument

Tags: mongodb, sitecore, mongodb-query, sitecore8

I have a set of mongodb documents with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : NUUID("58fbb893-dfe9-4f08-a761-5629d889647d"),
    "Identifiers" : {
        "IdentificationLevel" : 2,
        "Identifier" : "extranet\\test@test.com"
    },
    "Personal" : {
        "FirstName" : "Test",
        "Surname" : "Test"
    },    
    "Tags" : {
        "Entries" : {
            "ContactLists" : {
                "Values" : {
                    "0" : {
                        "Value" : "{292D8695-4936-4865-A413-800960626E6D}",
                        "DateTime" : ISODate("2015-04-30T09:14:45.549Z")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make a query with the mongo shell which finds all documents with a specific "Value" (e.g.{292D8695-4936-4865-A413-800960626E6D} in the Tag.Entries.ContactLists.Values path?

The structure is unfortunately locked by Sitecore, so it is not an options to use another structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your sample collection structure show `Values` is object, it contains only one `Value`. Also you must check for `Value` as it contains extra paranthesis. If you want to get `Value` from given structure try following query :

```
db.collection.find({
"Tags.Entries.ContactLists.Values.0.Value": "{292D8695-4936-4865-A413-800960626E6D}"
})
```

Comment: I thought I had tried that but apparently I had some errors in my query. It works!

Comment: Also you should not use dynamic keys like `0` in structure. It is not handy for writing queries.

Comment: I know - It is Sitecore which generates the data so unfortunately i cannot control the structure